# TensorFlow Recommenders: How to solve ValueError in computing scores when training a custom model with TFRS?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, matrix-multiplication, recommendation-engine

I'm new to TensorFlow Recommenders (TFRS) and trying to build a custom recommendation model using this library. I am encountering an issue when computing the scores in my custom model's compute_loss method. I have a user model and a stim model, both of which produce embeddings that I want to use to compute scores.

However, when I try to compute the scores using tf.matmul() or tf.einsum(), I keep getting a ValueError related to the dimensions of the embeddings. I have tried various methods to reshape and adjust the dimensions, but I can't seem to find a working solution.

Here's the relevant code for my custom model:

```
# User Dense layers
user_dense1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(flat_embeddings)
user_output = Dense(32, activation='relu')(user_dense1)
user_model = Model(inputs=[...], outputs=user_output)

# Stim Dense layers
stim_dense1 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense_stim)
stim_dense2 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(stim_dense1)
stim_output = stim_dense2
stim_model = Model(inputs=[stim_name_input], outputs=stim_output)

class StimmingRecommenderModel(tfrs.Model):
    ...
    def compute_loss(self, inputs, training=False):
        ...
        user_embeddings = user_model({...})
        stim_embeddings = stim_model({"name": stim_features["name"]})

        print(f"user_embeddings shape: {user_embeddings.shape}")
        print(f"stim_embeddings shape: {stim_embeddings.shape}")

        # Compute the scores using tf.matmul()
        scores = tf.matmul(user_embeddings, stim_embeddings, transpose_b=True)
        ...
        return self.task(labels, scores)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 32 for '{{node MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=true](MatMul/ExpandDims, args_1)' with input shapes: [?,1], [1,32].
```

I expected to be able to compute the scores using tf.matmul() or tf.einsum() with the appropriate reshaping of the embeddings. I tried the following methods:

1 Reshaping the embeddings with tf.expand_dims(), tf.squeeze(), and tf.reshape().

2 Using tf.einsum() with different combinations of indices.

However, none of these methods have resolved the error. I was expecting to compute the scores without encountering the ValueError related to the dimensions of the embeddings.

Thank you!